# Android: get a handler to the app's icon from an SDK

Tags: android, sdk, icons, android-notifications

I am building an Android SDK which sometimes need to display [notifications](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) to the user in the [notification drawer](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html):

[image]

Naturally, I would like to use the app icon when setting the [setSmallIcon()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setSmallIcon(int)) property of the [NotificationCompat.Builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html). The problem is that an SDK does not know in advance what is the icon of its embracing app.

**Is there a way to get a reference to the app icon asset programatically, in run time?**

Comment: Do u know the package name of the app?

Comment: @AlexChengalan Not in advance; it's a general purpose SDK that can be used with any old app.